# How to create and drop database in DB2 using maven script

Tags: database, maven, db2, maven-plugin

I am trying to run maven script and drop and create the databases.

This is my xml

```
.....
<plugin>
    <!-- Used to automatically drop (if any) and create a database prior 
        to running integration test cases. -->
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>sql-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.5</version>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.22</version>
        </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>db2.connector</groupId>
            <artifactId>db2.connector</artifactId>
            <version>10.5.0.1</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${basedir}/../data/target/db2jcc.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>db2.connector</groupId>
            <artifactId>db2.connector4</artifactId>
            <version>10.5.0.1</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${basedir}/../data/target/db2jcc4.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <configuration>
        <!-- common configuration shared by all executions -->
            <driver>com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver</driver>
            <username>db2inst1</username>
            <password>password</password>
            <url>jdbc:db2://192.168.0.81:50000/db</url>
            <forceMojoExecution>true</forceMojoExecution>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>drop-db-before-test-if-any</id>
                <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>execute</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <autocommit>true</autocommit>
                    <sqlCommand>drop database db</sqlCommand>
                    <onError>continue</onError>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
            <execution>
                <id>create-db</id>
                <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>execute</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <autocommit>true</autocommit>
                    <sqlCommand>create database db</sqlCommand>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
            <execution>
                <id>create-schema</id>
                <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>execute</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <url>jdbc:db2://192.168.0.81:50000/sample</url>
                    <autocommit>true</autocommit>
                    <srcFiles>
                        <srcFile>${basedir}/../data/src/main/resources/create_database_db2.sql</srcFile>
                    </srcFiles>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
.....
```

The error I get is

```
[ERROR] com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-104,
 SQLSTATE=42601, SQLERRMC=database;drop ;<program_or_package>, DRIVER=3.66.46
[INFO] 0 of 1 SQL statements executed successfully
```

Similar error for create db.

What am I doing wrong in this?

Comment: Is there a log on the server?  Can you show us?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a Maven expert, but the issue you're running into is that you're trying to run [`DROP DATABASE`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0001949.html) as a SQL command, when it is a [DB2 Command-Line processor](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0010409.html) command.

[This thread](http://bytes.com/topic/db2/answers/483572-how-do-we-execute-command-through-java) might be of some help, it's about running DB2 CLP commands in Java.

Answer (score 1):

As Bhamby said, you cannot execute a "create database", nor a "drop database" as a SQL command. That is the reason you are having those kind of errors.

**Command script via exec-maven-plugin**

What you can do is to execute a command from Maven, but before, you have to be sure that the DB2 environment is correctly loaded. You can use the [exec-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/) plugin, but instead of executing different commands to load the DB2 profile and then creating the database, what you can do is to write a script that will receive the database name as parameter, and the script will create the database. The problem here, is that you have to write one for Linux, and one for Windows. For example in linux:

create.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
. /home/db2inst1/sqllib/db2profile
db2 create db $1
```

The instance home directory here was: /home/db2inst1.

Also, you have to be sure, the user used to execute Maven has the necessary rights at the instance to create a new database. I mean, the user should be in the sysadm or sysctrl group: http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r5/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0001941.html

**Java**

You cannot create the database via Java, because the DB2 API does not provide a Java API for this. Instead, you can create a [C routine called](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r5/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.api.doc/doc/r0001446.html) from JNI and invoke it in Java. In this way, you can personalize the creation/dropping process from Java, and not from a script.